# Is there any way to get Realtime data from BigQuery SDK / API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I working on a project in which I’m facing a problem that I want to get real-time data from BigQuery dataset,
So I research hard I learn about web sockets like pusher and laravel-websocket, and I also test them also

but One thing I didn’t understand that how to do If I connect BigQuery SDK with my Laravel project then I didn’t find any event or method that BigQuery gives us to do so, because in my scenario most data comes from IoT devices and the device uses bigQueryAPI to feed data I also want that devices data real-time.

Then I found that there’s a way to connect BigQuery Dataset with firebase and then firebase gives us an event whenever row fed in the dataset.

I just want to know Is there’s any that without a firebase solution I can do it?
because the above solution is not free I have to pay firebase to avail of this feature?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

IoT devices can post the data to pub/sub instead of BigQuery, from pub/sub one consumer(Ex:Dataflow) can read and insert the data into BigQuery and you can create consumer for your custom needs.

Comment: noted your word, but my clients already use only BigQuery and all data from devices inserts directly into BigQuery datasets, I want to connect  BigQuery with WebSockets 
is there any good documentation like how it's actually possible if it's ?